# my site show this symbol (::) between site title and tagline

Tags: php, title, headers, wp-title

i have a web site with a problem in a tag "`<title>`" , i see between site title and tagline this character (::) in home page and  only one (:) in other page, in my header.php theme i have this :

```
 <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

i tried also :

```
 <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

but i see same character:

after this i tried :

```
<?php $symbolo="|"; ?>
 <title><?php wp_title($symbolo); ?></title>
```

and show this in frontend-sourcecode title:

> this is a title :| this is a tagline

in normal circonstances  `<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>`  with this i see for homepage this:

> this is a title :: this is a tagline

and for other page , i see this:

> this is a title : this is a tagline

now i want use a symbol (|) instead (:) like this:

> this is a title | this is a tagline

how solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you install any SEO plugin? Yoast SEO maybe. Or plugin that related to SEO. It usually overwrite the title setting.
Check your plugin first please.

Comment: not have never plugin active, i tried also rename the plugin folder , but the problem persist, with other theme work